# How can we give grant and revoke permissions by Entity Framework code-first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

All I want is to give the permissions to the user from Entity Framework (using the code first approach) that is like DDL, DML commands to a certain user.

Comment: By permissions, you want to restrict users when accessing certain pages?

Comment: yes is there any way?

Comment: yes hang on let me make an answer, the answer will be about how to setup ASPNetUserRoles

Answer (score 1):

The steps below will help you create user, create roles, assign user to roles, and limit their access depending on their role.

1. Open your Solution in Visual Studio
2. Tools > Nuget Package Manager Console > Enter `Enable-Migrations`
3. Open Migrations > `Configuration.cs`
4. Use this as your seed method;

```
protected override void Seed(ISPRC.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
  var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
  var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

  userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(userManager)
  {
     AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
  };

  var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

  // Create a User Role
  if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
  {
     var role = new IdentityRole();
     role.Name = "Admin";
     roleManager.Create(role);
  }

  if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "admin@mail.com"))
  {
      var user = new ApplicationUser
      {
         UserName = "admin@mail.com",
         Email = "admin@mail.com",
         EmailConfirmed = true,
      };

      // Create User
      userManager.Create(user, "Password@777");

      // Add User to Admin Role
      userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
   }
}
```

5. To limit certain roles in accessing your controllers or actions, add `[Authorize]` or `[Authorize(Roles="Admin,User")]`

The controller below will only allow Logged-in users that are of Admin role. If they're role does not match the requirement, they will be automatically redirected to login page.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
   private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

   public ActionResult Accounts()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

6. Tools > Nuget Package Manager Console > Enter `Update-Database`

Comment: thanks a lot, it is really useful but all I need is the DB level, not the application level can please find me the way in DB level it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Migration Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations), or you can switch to a database-first workflow, and manage the database schema with another tool, and periodically [reverse engineer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding) the schema into a code-based model.

Comment: In there any way in the DB level?